# Can I download Progress DataDirect DB2 scripts that create the packages somewhere?

Tags: jdbc, db2, driver, progress, datadirect

I am using DataDirect JDBC to connect to DB2 I am getting errors when the driver first tries to connect and create and run the package scripts.  I see in DataDirect's doc that you can run the scripts manually but I can't find them.  Are these downloadable somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a link you are looking for?
[HOW TO CREATE OR MODIFY DB2 BINDING PACKAGES ON UNIX/LINUX](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000024847)

Or this one?
[Creating a DB2 Package](http://www.stylusstudio.com/doc/jdbcug.pdf#page44)

Comment: Thanks.  That is the link that describes how to run the scripts.  I am looking for the scripts themselves.  I am using Adobe ColdFusion that embeds datadirect drivers so I  don't have the full product.